# R2OpenBUGS Error: node not stochastic

Tags: r, models, stochastic, volatility

I have a specific problem in Running R2OpenBUGS in R. But it runs perfectly well in OpenBUGS.
I want to understand what the problem is.

Here is my code:
model volatility;
const n=180;
{

    # likelihood: joint distribution of ys

    for (t in 1:n) 
{ 
yisigma2[t] <- 1/exp(theta[t]);

    y[t] ~ dnorm(0,yisigma2[t]);

}

## prior distributions

mu ~ dnorm(0,0.1);

phistar ~ dbeta(20,1.5);

itau2 ~ dgamma(2.5,0.025);

beta <- exp(mu/2);

phi <- 2*phistar-1;

tau <- sqrt(1/itau2);

theta0 ~ dnorm(mu,itau2);

thmean[1] <- mu + phi*(theta0-mu);

theta[1] ~ dnorm(thmean[1],itau2);

for (t in 2:n) 

 {

         thmean[t] <- mu + phi*(theta[t-1]-mu);

             theta[t] ~ dnorm(thmean[t],itau2);


 }

}

R Code:

svm.sim <- bugs(data, inits, model.file = "C:/Documents and Settings/code.txt",
 parameters = c("mu", "phi", "tau"),
 n.chains = 1, n.iter = 1000, codaPkg = TRUE,debug=TRUE)

and here is the error shown in log of OpenBUGS when I run it from R:

model is syntactically correct

data loaded

model compiled

this component of node is not stochastic phi error pos 25

unable to generate initial values for node  of type UpdaterNormal.StdUpdater

model must be initialized before updating

model must be initialized before monitors used

model must be initialized before monitors used

model must be initialized before monitors used

model must be initialized before monitors used

model must be initialized before DIC can be monitored

model must be initialized before updating

model must be initialized before monitors used

DIC monitor not set

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank You and Regards

Dinakar

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with a slight modification (see below) and it seemed to work fine. I did specify the value n as data, and let OpenBUGS generate initial values itself. Is it an issue with how you specified your inits?

```
    sink("stack_model.txt")
    cat("
    model{
    # likelihood: joint distribution of ys 
    for (t in 1:n) 
    { 
    yisigma2[t] <- 1/exp(theta[t])
    y[t] ~ dnorm(0,yisigma2[t])
  }
  mu ~ dnorm(0,0.1)
  phistar ~ dbeta(20,1.5) 
  itau2 ~ dgamma(2.5,0.025)
  beta <- exp(mu/2)
  phi <- 2*phistar-1
  tau <- sqrt(1/itau2)
  theta0 ~ dnorm(mu,itau2) 
  thmean[1] <- mu + phi*(theta0-mu) 
  theta[1] ~ dnorm(thmean[1],itau2) 
  for (t in 2:n) 
  { 
    thmean[t] <- mu + phi*(theta[t-1]-mu) 
    theta[t] ~ dnorm(thmean[t],itau2) 

  } 
}",fill=TRUE)
sink()
win.data<-list(n=180)
svm.sim <- bugs(win.data, inits=NULL, model.file = "stack_model.txt", parameters = c("mu", "phi", "tau"), n.chains = 2, n.iter = 1000, DIC=F, debug=TRUE,  codaPkg =TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you add a comment on what you changed specifically